# How to escape character '{' in string method format()?

Tags: python

I am trying to use string format() method to create a connection string.

Below is my code :

```
connStr = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER={s};PORT=1443;DATABASE={d};UID={u};PWD={p}'.format(s = server, d = database, u = username, p = password)
```

It will get following error:

File ".\sqltest.py", line 9, in 
    connStr = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER={s};PORT-1443;DATABASE={d};UID={u};PWD={p}'.format(s = se
rver, d = database, u = username, p = password)
KeyError: 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server\'

Comment: Probably with `\\`?

Comment: Google search keywords I used to find the dupe: [`stackoverflow python string format escape brace`](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+python+string+format+escape+brace).

Comment: use {{ }} try this `connStr = 'DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}};SERVER={s};PORT=1443;DATABASE={d};UID={u};PWD={p}'.format(s = server, d = database, u = username, p = password)`